# Woocommerce form has no action?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking at the code in form-edit-address.php and I am very confused. I need to know what function is called when the 'Save address' button is clicked. However I can't find anything that links this button to a function. Am I missing something here?

```
<form method="post">

    <h3><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_edit_address_title', $page_title, $load_address ); ?></h3><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>

    <div class="woocommerce-address-fields">
        <?php do_action( "woocommerce_before_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

        <div class="woocommerce-address-fields__field-wrapper">
            <?php
            foreach ( $address as $key => $field ) {
                woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, wc_get_post_data_by_key( $key, $field['value'] ) );
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( "woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="button" name="save_address" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-edit_address', 'woocommerce-edit-address-nonce' ); ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_address" />
        </p>
    </div>

</form>
```

What tells the program what to do when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no explicit `action`, the currently active URL is used (standard HTML). So if you're on `/foo`, the POST request will be sent to `/foo` - in this probably directly to `form-edit-address.php`.

Comment: `form-edit-address.php` does not look like it contains any code to handle a POST request. The url path is /my-account/edit-address/billing/. I wonder if this path is being redirected to Class WC_Form_Handler.

Comment: Yes, you're looking for [the `save_address` method in that class](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_form_handlersave_address/) as far as I know.